# Java Recursion game theory get best move

Tags: java, recursion

I have been tasked to write a function that will find the best move for the computer to make for part of a backtracking algorithm.  My solution finds a winnable answer but not a best answer.  I am having trouble figuring out a way to keep a value assigned to the different options that won't get reset during the next recursive call.  So if it goes through moves 1,2,3,4 and 2 and 3 both lead to a winnable solution it will take 3 and not 2 even if 2 would be the better choice.  I can see why in my code this happens but I can't seem to think through how to fix it. I tried with the wins and total wins variable but this doesn't seem to be working.  So once again the function works to find a winnable avenue but won't always pick the best of the winnable moves.  Any help would be much appreciated

```
Move bestMove = null;


    int totalwins= 0;
    public Move findbest(Game g) throws GameException {
        int wins = 0;

        PlayerNumber side = g.SECOND_PLAYER;
        PlayerNumber opp = g.FIRST_PLAYER;
        Iterator<Move> moves = g.getMoves();
        while(moves.hasNext()){

            Move m = moves.next();
            //System.out.println(m + " Totalwins " + totalwins);
            Game g1 = g.copy();
            g1.make(m);
            //System.out.println("Turn: " + g.whoseTurn());
            if(!g1.isGameOver()){
                bestMove = findbest(g1);
            }else{
                if(g1.winner() == side ){
                    bestMove = m;
                    wins++;
                }else if(g1.winner() == opp){
                    wins--;
                }
                if(wins > totalwins){
                    totalwins += wins;
                    bestMove = m;
                }
            }
            if(bestMove == null){//saftey so it won't return a null if there is no winnable move.  
                bestMove = m;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("Totalwins = " + totalwins);
        return bestMove;
    }
```

Comment: In order to determine the best of something, you must have a ranking system. How is a move better than another? You must have a clear way to compare moves. Then, it will depend on the type of game. In some games it is possible to calculate a best move by some algorithm. In other cases, you are better off calculating all possible moves and then sorting them. Your case seems to be the latter. To backtrack with recursion, you must find a way to determine, at each recursive call, which move is best, and return that.

Comment: I was hoping to come up with a  way that would count the number of winnable states that could be achieved from each move.  Then which ever move has the most winnable states would be returned

Comment: Peter3, take a look at recursive and rank-/weight- based algorithms like A* (pronounced "A, Star", a path-finding algorithm common in games' AI). It might give you (very) useful hints and/or inspiration. This is also linked to, and an example of, what afsantos said. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you need to have some sort of rating system to determine which move really is the best.

Then, make a global variable `Move bestMove` and, instead of having `findBest` return the "best move", simply have it check to see if the current move is a winning one and, if so, also check to see if its rating is better than that of the current `bestMove.` If both of these conditions are true, then assign the current move to `bestMove.`

Comment: You can keep track of the highest ranked move while you add them, no need to iterate over the list

Comment: Sorry, just wrote a similar algorithm recently where I did in fact have to store all returned values in an `ArrayList` and iterate over them, so my mind was in the wrong place. Edited my answer.

Comment: I had the global variable of bestMove already above. I tried having the weight set with the wins and totalwins variables and to assign bestMove the higher of the two.  I appreciate the help.  I am close to finishing it up on my desktop and I will post what i ended up doing